# Checking if a network drive is working or not

Tags: windows, vbscript

I've already a vbs script that checks if it is mapped a network drive in a server:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set colDrives = objFSO.Drives

For Each objDrive in colDrives
    If CBool(objDrive.DriveType = 3) Then ' Network disk
           If (objFSO.DriveExists(objDrive.DriveLetter) = True) Then
              Wscript.Echo "Network Drive Mapped : " & objDrive.DriveLetter
           End If
    End If
Next
```

Problem is that it doesn't say if that network drive is still alive or not.
For example, in one server there are 3 network drives:

[image]

But one of them (drive Y:) has lost connection.

[image]

I am trying to find out what vbs command can give that result, but I haven't found it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Drive object "IsReady" method.  If it's TRUE, the drive is available.